# Custom segue with left to right animation going diagonal instead

Tags: ios6, uiviewanimation, uistoryboardsegue

I'm building an app where the first view has a menu panel, and I want this panel to stick around for the life of the app.  The only places the user can "go" are reachable via buttons on this panel (a UICollectionView).  In case it matters, this app is landscape-only, and iOS 6-only.

In order to make this work I created a custom segue, which removes everything from the view except for the menu panel, then adds the new view controller's view as a subview, sets the new view's frame to the bounds of the superview, and sends the new view to the back (so it's behind the menu panel). I call viewWill/DidDisappear from prepareForSegue, because otherwise they don't get called.

It may sound kludgy (it does to me), but it works fine except for one thing - the new view comes up from the bottom.  It looks funny.

I then tried adding my own animation block - I initially locate the view off to the left, then animate it into place.  I send it to the back in the completion block for the animation.  This seems perfectly logical, and the frame values are all what they should be.  But this one is worse - the view comes in from the lower left corner.

Can anyone suggest a way to make this work?  Here's my current perform method:

```
- (void)perform {
    MainMenuViewController *sourceVC = (MainMenuViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationVC = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

    for (UIView *subview in [sourceVC.mainView subviews]) {
        // don't remove the menu panel or the tab
        if (![subview isKindOfClass:[UICollectionView class]] && [subview.gestureRecognizers count] == 0) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    [sourceVC.mainView addSubview:destinationVC.view];

    CGRect finalFrame = sourceVC.mainView.bounds;
    CGRect frame = finalFrame;
    frame.origin.x = finalFrame.origin.x - finalFrame.size.width;
    destinationVC.view.frame = frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        destinationVC.view.frame = finalFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // make sure it ends up behind the main menu panel
        [sourceVC.mainView sendSubviewToBack:destinationVC.view];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a simple error - I needed to set destinationVC's frame before calling addSubview.  Setting it afterwards was triggering the unwanted animation.